# Upgrading from Umbraco 7.15 to 8 (Detected current version 0.0.0)

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

I am trying to upgrade the underlying Umbraco database from 7.15.8 to 8.

What I have done is spin up a vanilla Umbraco 8, then pointed it to the 7 DB.

The issue is that when I go running the upgrade see the following method

```
Detected current version 0.0.0 (unknown), which needs to be upgraded to 8.
```

Once run the upgrade I then get the error

The database failed to upgrade. ERROR: The database configuration failed with the following message: Could not get current version from web.config Umbraco.Core.ConfigurationStatus appSetting.

What I have tried setting the value in the web.config, but it doesn't make any difference.

```
<add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="7.15.8" />
```

Comment: Try setting the umbracoVersion app setting to the current version of the database (7.x.x) in the web.config file…

Answer (score 1):

Could you verify the version 7.15.8 you are putting in web.config matches with the latest version in [umbracoMigration] table

Comment: I have done this will logging into the CMS before trying to upgrade and it is correct. 

I tried adding <add key="Umbraco.Core.ConfigurationStatus" value="7.15.8" />

But then I get the error The database configuration failed with the following message: Unknown state "{init-7.15.8}".

Comment: Its strange, i used something similar approach to the one mentioned in below repo with extra steps like upgrading data from int id to udi then followed steps mentioned in this repo: https://github.com/LottePitcher/Umbraco-v7-Upgrader and upgraded to all the way to 10